# Azure Templates Support For AKS Node Pools

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-rm-template

AKS has recently released support for node pools https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools . Are node pools supported in ARM templates? If so what is the syntax for using them? I was not able to find any documentation about ARM template support online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm afraid you cannot use the Azure Template to create AKS with multiple node pools currently. In the document that you provide, you need to enable the VMSS to create AKS with multiple node pools. It's the agent type which you just can enable it in the [CLI preview version for AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/aks-preview/aks?view=azure-cli-latest). And you cannot find it in the template.

There is no difference in both templates for single node pool and multiple node pools when you create it except the elements in the property `agentPoolProfiles`:

```
"agentPoolProfiles": [
                    {
                        "name": "nodepool1",
                        "count": 1,
                        "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
                        "osDiskSizeGB": 100,
                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                        "maxPods": 110,
                        "osType": "Linux"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "secnodepool",
                        "count": 1,
                        "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
                        "osDiskSizeGB": 100,
                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                        "maxPods": 110,
                        "osType": "Linux"
                    }
                ],
```

I think the multiple node pools will be available in the template when the it really publish, not the preview version. So you just need to wait patiently.

**Update**

Apologize for the above wrong answer. In the "2019-02-01" "apiVersion", you can already set the agent type as "VirtualMachineScaleSets" in the property "type" in "agentPoolProfiles". The mistake that I test it in "2018-03-31" "apiVersion".

Comment: why do you think they are not available? you can create multiple node pool aks with arm template at least since december (or maybe january). https://4c74356b41.com/post5785

Comment: @4c74356b41 The same setting in the template but no success. It just creates only one pool. The multiple node pools need the vmss agent and there is no property to set it. Do you really create multiple node pools through the template you provide? Or just deploy it succeeds?

Comment: yes, it does create multiple node pools. it wouldn't be supported, and only the first pool would be scalable. but it would be possible to upgrade the cluster

Comment: @4c74356b41 That's it. It does not support by AKS even if it can create multiple pools in kubernetes cluster. It's more k8s than AKS. And it does not have the feathers of AKS with multiple node pools.

Comment: you can create aks with vmss with arm template. not sure i follow the argument

Comment: @4c74356b41 No, you cannot create vmss as the AKS node pool through template. It does not support now. Unless you use the aks-engine.

Comment: @4c74356b41 If you are so excellent, just try what you think is right and give your answer. I don't want to talk with the impolite you.

Comment: i'm not excellent. but I try not to give misleading answers. this is harmful, dont you understand? people might think this is not possible because of your answer. they might even ditch Azure altogether because this is not possible to automate properly.

Answer (score 3):

here's a working template example:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/ManagedClusters",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "name": "aks-test",
            "location": "eastus",
            "properties": {
                "kubernetesVersion": "1.13.5",
                "dnsPrefix": "xxx",
                "agentPoolProfiles": [
                    {
                        "name": "nodepool1",
                        "count": 1,
                        "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
                        "osDiskSizeGB": 100,
                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                        "maxPods": 110,
                        "osType": "Linux",
                        "enable_auto_scaling": true,
                        "min_count": 1,
                        "max_count": 3,
                        "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "nodepool2",
                        "count": 1,
                        "vmSize": "Standard_DS2_v2",
                        "osDiskSizeGB": 100,
                        "storageProfile": "ManagedDisks",
                        "maxPods": 110,
                        "osType": "Linux",
                        "enable_auto_scaling": true,
                        "min_count": 1,
                        "max_count": 3,
                        "type": "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
                    }
                ],
                "linuxProfile": {
                    "adminUsername": "azureuser",
                    "ssh": {
                        "publicKeys": [
                            {
                                "keyData": "key"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "servicePrincipalProfile": {
                    "clientId": "yyy",
                    "secret": "zzz"
                },
                "enableRBAC": true,
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkPlugin": "kubenet",
                    "podCidr": "10.244.0.0/16",
                    "serviceCidr": "10.0.0.0/16",
                    "dnsServiceIP": "10.0.0.10",
                    "dockerBridgeCidr": "172.17.0.1/16"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

you'd need to enable vmss preview before running this.

[image]

Comment: whats impolite in pointing out wrong answers? this is not the first time you've given a wrong answer and you dont even retract\edit them. thats impolite\harmful and misleading. you only care about points on this site, which dont even mean anything @CharlesXu